# Coherent state basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, linear-algebra, coherent-states

I'm learning about coherent states in a more in depth lesson the the quantum harmonic oscillator. Coherent states are eigenstates of the lowering operator. In my head this is just saying: since any arbitrary energy eigenstate can be brought down to 0 by successive applications of the lowering operator, each of those states are also eigenstates of the lowering operator.

But are the energy eigenstates of the Q.H.O. eigenstates of the lowering operator, or is there only 1 eigenstate of the lowering operator, which is  a superposition of all possible energy eigenstates? What do the basis vectors look like for coherent state space, and how does this differ from the energy basis?

Comment: "since any arbitrary energy eigenstate can be brought down to 0 by successive applications of the lowering operator, each of those states are also eigenstates of the lowering operator." If each of these states were an eigenstate of the lowering operator, the lowering operator wouldn't change the state.

Comment: For your second question: how do you write out the coherent state explicitly?

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state). What is your question *now*?

Comment: @CosmasZachos You post a link to wikipedia as though I haven't tried to figure this out on my own and am just stupid/lazy. Comments like this are unhelpful, condescending, and have no place on stack exchange. Just because a concept may have been easy for you to understand on your first or second read, doesn't mean it will come as easily to everyone else.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with the required reading, you may, of course ignore it. It answers all your questions.

Comment: @Dutonic Did my comments answer your questions? If not, what is left unclear?

Answer (score 3):

Denoting the energy eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator by $| n \rangle$ ($n=0,1,2,\ldots$), the lowering operator $a$ acts on them as $a |n\rangle =\sqrt{n} |n-1 \rangle$ for $n=1,2, \ldots$ and $a |0\rangle=0$, which shows that the energy eigenstates $|1\rangle, \, |2\rangle, \ldots$ are NOT eigenstates of the lowering operator $a$. ONLY the ground state $|0\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the lowering operator with eigenvalue zero.

The eigenvalue equation of the lowering operator, $a |z \rangle = z |z \rangle$, has a solution for ALL complex numbers $z$. Up to a phase factor, the normalized solution of this eigenvalue equation for a given $ z \in \mathbf{C}$ is uniquely by

$|z\rangle = e^{-|z|^2/2}e^{z a^\dagger} |0 \rangle$.

Employing the series expansion for the second exponential, the coherent state $|z\rangle$ can be written as a superposition of the energy eigenstates $|n\rangle$ as

$|z\rangle = e^{-|z|^2/2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle$,

where $|n\rangle = \frac{(a^\dagger)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|0\rangle$ was used.